# Proceeds of house sale for study loan

Tags: india, loans, student-loan

Sale of House proceeds is 50lacs. profit from sale of property 15 lacs.
I have student loan 30 lacs.
Should I pay student loan first or buy property. My all transactions are in in INDIA.

Comment: “Should” is tricky.  What’s the interest rate on your student loan?  Why did you sell the property?  What other property would you buy?  How much of a loan would you take to buy the property?  Can you afford both payments?

Comment: Why do you want to buy the property? As an investment or to live there?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: General rule: If you have a loan at rate L, and an investment opportunity that returns I (after tax considerations), it's usually better to pay off the loan if L > I.

Comment: The house sale is irrelevant. However, buying property may have other benefits beside the purely financial, as it may be a place to live.